# Unable to access Google Cloud SQL (old) console

Tags: google-cloud-sql

As of today, I can no longer access the Google Cloud SQL web console. For as long as we've been using Google Cloud SQL (about a year now) we've always been able to open the old google API console to get to the SQL prompt, but today the "noredirect" link stopped working and it always redirects to the new Google developers console which has no way to run SQL against the database.  The URL we are using is like this:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/2/?noredirect&pli=1#project:999999999999:sql:instance:myprojectid:db01

Any ideas why this stopped working, and any alternatives for an SQL web interface?  I would prefer to not have to setup a static IP and connect from a MySQL client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This service has been turned down. There are several alternatives:

1) You can use the new "gcloud beta sql connect" command that is included in the Cloud SDK. Unless you machine supports IPv6 (unlikely) you will need to enable a IPv4 address for your instance.

2) You can connect using the normal mysql client. Again, unless you machine support IPv6 (unlikely) you will need to enable a IPv4 address for your instance. You will also need to authorize your IP address.

3) You can deploy PHPMyAdmin on Google App Engine which will provide you with a web console.